# Making inner DIVs overlap another outer DIV

Tags: html, css

In the example below there is a blue div followed by a red div beneath it. They are styled to have a set height. In the upper blue div there is another div, a white div, whose content is too long to be displayed entirely within the upper blue div.

What I would like to have happen is for the white div to overlay both divs. I don't want to remove the white div from the blue div because the white div will ultimately act as a popup menu for other items to be added to the blue div. So it belongs in the blue div I just want it to temporarily overlay both divs.

Is there a way to make that happen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
<title>Overlay</title>
<style type="text/css">
#top-div{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#bottom-div{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#my-list{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>        
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-div">
  <div id="my-list">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
      <li>six</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom-div">I am the footer</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the my-list css rules, add:

```
float: left;
position: absolute;
```

The float will put the div overlaying both the background div's. 
The absolute will prevent the text in the background div's from wrapping around the popup div.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, make sure that the parent div "top-div" also has a position set (most likely "position:relative"). Otherwise "my-list" will position itself to the first non-static element.

Answer (score 0):

Since parents have a higher `z-index` than its children, you need to change the default browser stacking behavior. Add `position: relative` to each element, and then specify a `z-index` on the parent and its children. The `z-index` for the children should be higher than the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#my-list{
  width: 100px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```